# Elasticsearch with Yii 2.0: Error: Elasticsearch request failed: 7 - Failed to connect to ##.##.##.### port 9200: Connection refused

Tags: elasticsearch, yii2

I have Elasticsearch properly configured on my server. I can do everything from the command line using cURL. I can even connect to it using cURL from a PHP script outside Yii. However, I can't seem to get it to work from within Yii 2.0.

In my config, I have:

```
'elasticsearch' => [
            'class' => 'yii\elasticsearch\Connection',
            'nodes' => [
                ['http_address' => 'localhost:9200'],
                // configure more hosts if you have a cluster
            ],
        ],
```

But when I try to do a simple query in Yii, I get this error. Note how it's using my server ip address rather than 'localhost' or '172.0.0.1'. Note: I've hashed out my ip address for sercurity.

```
Elasticsearch Database Exception – yii\elasticsearch\Exception
Elasticsearch request failed: 7 - Failed to connect to ##.##.##.### port 9200: Connection refused
Error Info: Array
(
    [requestMethod] => GET
    [requestUrl] => http://##.##.##.###:9200/profiles/profile/_search
    [requestBody] => {"size":100,"query":{"match_all":{}}}
    [responseHeaders] => Array
        (
        )
    [responseBody] => 
)
```

Comment: I have the same issue, what version of Elasticsearch are you running on your server?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this error by updating the version of Elasticsearch to something > 1.3.0 as this is the minimum requirement for YIISOFT/YII2-ELASTICSEARCH

run `curl -X GET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200'` to check what version you are running.

Answer (score 0):

First follow this steps to download elastic search.

```
wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.5.2.tar.gz
mkdir es
tar -xf elasticsearch-1.5.2.tar.gz -C es
cd es
./bin/elasticsearch
```

Then you must be able to access to localhost:9200 and get something like this below :

```
{
  "name" : "Sigyn",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.4.0",
    "build_hash" : "ce9f0c7394dee074091dd1bc4e9469251181fc55",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-08-29T09:14:17Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.2"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Then secondly,follow instruction in https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-elasticsearch. Then you are done